# React Native component not getting updated when firebase realtime database listener returns a new value

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to react and I am building my final year project using it. I am currently trying to display the game times, however when I add a new game or update a game time the component is not getting re-rendered without me manually refreshing the page.
My code is below:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import * as firebase from 'firebase';



class AdvancedSearchScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      games: []
    }
    this.props.watchUserData();
    var database = firebase.database();
    var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('games');
    commentsRef.on('child_added', (data) => {
      this.state.games.push(data.val());
    });

    commentsRef.on('child_changed', (data) => {
      this.state.games.push(data.val());
    });
  }
  render() {  
    return(
    <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.container}> 
      {this.state.games.map(type => <Text>{type.gameTime}</Text>)}
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default AdvancedSearchScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think you should move you state update to a `componentDidMount()` using the `this.state.games.push(data.val());` will not trigger a new render, you need to use the `setState()` function, something like this should work for you:

```
class AdvancedSearchScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      games: []
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.watchUserData();
    var database = firebase.database();
    var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('games');
    commentsRef.on('child_added', (data) => {
      const newItem = data.val()
      this.setState({games: [...this.state.games, newItem]})
    });

    commentsRef.on('child_changed', (data) => {
      const newItem = data.val()
      this.setState({games: [...this.state.games, newItem]})
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {this.state.games.map(type => <Text>{type.gameTime}</Text>)}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default AdvancedSearchScreen;
```

something like this should force the render.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue. I just added a small check to make it work when it is setting up the data for the first time. When it is adding data for the first time i need to check if the games array is null, if so i set the game to the newItem, else I add the newItem to the games list